# Render dimensions

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, dimensions

How can i extend my render resolution. I tried changing the X,Y values under the dimensions tab. However changing them only results in an Y length increase/decrease. X dimension stays the same. 
[image]

This is the view i wish to achieve. I would like to add that, moving the camera is not an option for me.

Comment: Did you try to choose one preset in Render Presets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution of the image while affecting the actual pixel dimensions does not affect the focal length(or zoom) of the camera.  Because of this behavior in your case if you wanted for the image to be wider you could adjust the aspect ratio of the camera(to make it wider), then select the camera, go to the object data panel and decrease the focal length of the camera.

[image]

Comment: As there appears to be a reason to not move the camera, adjusting the cameras ShiftX value (under focal length) may also be helpful to reframe the desired area.

Comment: Yes, if you wanted that extra portion to be on the right, you can use the ShiftX value in order to move the rendered portion to the right.